# Why postgres won't map columns correctly

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-models

I have this query to update another table but getting error.

```
With CTE AS
(Select employer_id, employee_id, start_date, end_date, hourly_rate, end_date - start_date AS time_worked
 FROM payroll_timesheet)
INSERT INTO payroll_timelog 
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE employee_id = 1;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "employee_id" is of type integer but expression is of type timestamp with time zone
LINE 5: SELECT employer_id, employee_id, start_date, end_date, hourl...
                                         ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

It seems to be mapping `employee_id` with `start_date`.

Or is there a syntax error in the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current error is an excellent reason for why you should *always* explicitly list out the column names of the target table in an insert.  You should have used something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT employer_id, employee_id, start_date, end_date, hourly_rate,
           end_date - start_date AS time_worked
    FROM payroll_timesheet
)

INSERT INTO payroll_timelog (employer_id, employee_id, start_date, end_date, hourly_rate,
                             time_worked)
SELECT employer_id, employee_id, start_date, end_date, hourly_rate, time_worked
FROM cte
WHERE employee_id = 1;
```

You might have to change the column names of the target `payroll_timelog` table to match.  Your current error is happening because Postgres is using the default column order, in the absence of your specifying the column order you want.